# python : shift values along a curve

Tags: python, math, interpolation, curve, points

I am trying to figure out a way to do this sort of thing.

[image: (see image) --> curve point shifting based on a global value]

I would be happy to hear any suggestions on this type of interpolation.

I have 2 fixed values `A` and `H`, and `n` extra random values in between.
In my example they are on a path, although I would be happy also if I could figure out how to solve it for a straight line.

Passing a global variable to my script I would like to displace these in between points in such a way that they are changed to gradually increasing/decreasing their distance between themselves and the two extremes accordingly (incrementally as shown on the image).

Comment: It is sufficient to select points on the X-axis as a function of a parameter. Maybe you can take piecewise convex combinations between `np.logspace`,  `np.linspace` and `np.logspace` in reverse.

Comment: So are these variables on a path, or are they random? If you've got `n` randoms in between, they're probably not on a simple path...

Comment: these 'points' are randomly picked based on the lenght 'value' of a spline curve in my case.
Alto i have a way to move these 'points' on the spline using some 'tricks',  therefore i would need to only solve the proper interpolation of the points values to make it work.
At this time i don't need to figure out how to make also the spline interpolation between these points.
also Thank you @YakymPirozhenko for the suggestion, altho i would prefer not to rely on external libraries at this time, due to some restrictions.

Comment: to further clarify
Imagine that instead of a curve was just a straight line,my starting point A has value 0, point H is the end point of the line, say it has a value along the lenght of 10 (random number based on how long the spline would be, say 10 units)
Now , in between these two points i want to pick 6 extra random points (based on random 'distance value ' between 0 and 10)

Now using a percentage attribute, i want to make these randomly  picked points to 'move' to a different value on the line, so that they look like the image above, in relation to eachother and the in - out points.

Comment: It feels like you need to do more work before asking this question: if you want to do this sort of thing, first say what you mean with that. What exact thing do you start with, what exact thing or things do you want to do? Right now you're asking people to recommend you how to do things, which is borderline off topic as a question asking people to come up with solutions to a vague problem for you. What do you want to actually do? Draw some more intermediary pictures for yourself, how is the point distribution moving along the curve? Can you determine which mathematical behaviour that is?

Comment: 'Can you determine which mathematical behaviour that is?' 
 No. 
That is exactly the question, i can't quite figure out what i would need to get that behaviour, matematichally speaking.. 
I am researching a little more on what @YakymPirozhenko suggested,and what type of interpolation method would be the closest one.
thanks